# Offline version of a web site

Tags: php, lamp

I've written a web app in PHP and MySQL that permits users to insert orders from a catalog.

The customer now asked me to create a version of the website that runs on the agent's PC even when they are not connected to the Internet. they must insert orders and then, when connected, send the orders to the DB. The agent's webserver has to be synchronized with the product images and previous orders.

Do you know what can I use to obtain this result? I've seen [Server2go](http://www.server2go-web.de/index.html), but it runs only on Windows. I would like something more portable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll probably need to look at html5 and client-side databases, which you can sync next time a connection is made.

You'll need to do some magic as you won't be running PHP anymore, it will all be on the client machine, so Javascript will probably be your weapon of choice.

Answer (score 0):

server2go looks like it will not synchronize once a connection to the server has been made.

There may be some turn key solutions for this, however, these type of off-line web applications usually require that they be designed with this in mind.

This question offers some more insight on the topic:
[Offline web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987509/offline-web-application)